# MySQL multiple columns as unordered sets

Tags: mysql, set

I'm somewhat new to MySQL and SQL in general, so hopefully this isn't a simple question.

I have a table that represents items in a customer's basket at checkout. This table represents a situation in which a customer is limited to 3 items, so I currently have a column for each item in the basket. It looks like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
+   id   |   item1   |   item2   |   item3   |   val   |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

where `val` is just some value associated with the basket. The ordering of the items means nothing in terms of my processing, so in theory I would like to have them represented as an unordered set. This means that a row of `(i1,i2,i3,val)` is functionally equivalent to `(i2,i1,i3,val)`.

My question is, how do I implement this in my table and/or in SQL such that selecting `(i3,i2,i1,val)` will return the row for `(i1,i2,i3,val)`?

I also need to have something that catches uniqueness when I'm inserting. For example, if I insert `(i2,i3,i1,newval)`, I would want the table to update `(i1,i2,i3,val)` to be `(i1,i2,i3,newval)`.

Comment: There are more than one solution. 1 relies of a model architecture change, another on triggers, another on stored procedures and another on a mix between triggers and stored procedures. Pick the one you prefer.

Comment: @Sebas, I am able to change my model architecture, and my primary concern is performance of a SELECT. So, whichever solution gives me the best performance when querying the database is what I would choose.

Comment: what's the datatype of item1,2 and 3?

Comment: also, is the id column the customer's id?

Comment: item1,2, and 3 are varchars, and the id is the customer's id.

Comment: 1. See normalization. 2. Normalize your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could standardise your model by using a 0 to many relation between customer and item:

```
-- assuming the existing table to be named `yourtable`
-- assuming your customer's table to be named `customer`
-- assuming your customer's id in the customer's table to be named `id`
-- assuming innodb (remove fk constraint if not)

CREATE TABLE `customer_item` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_customer` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    `item` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=innodb
SELECT NULL AS `id`, t.id AS `id_customer`, t.`item`
FROM (
    SELECT id, item1 AS `item`
    FROM
        yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT id, item2 AS `item`
    FROM
        yourtable
    UNION
    SELECT id, item3 AS `item`
    FROM
        yourtable
) t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
;

CREATE INDEX UNIQUE `idx_customer_item_cust` ON `customer_item` (`id_customer`, `item`);
ALTER TABLE `customer_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_item_cust` FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


-- once you check the data is consistent:

DROP TABLE `yourtable`;
```

Once that done, no item could be possibly inserted twice for the same customer.
Please note:

- the union select skips duplicates already at table creation, in case some items were repeated for some customers
- your data is normalised, from the customer to item point of view
- your data is still not normalised, from the item point of view. You should have an item table, and the `customer_item` table should reference the id of items in the `item` table instead of using item names or description for varchars.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. So I combine the many columns into one column sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @user2979931 the sort happens at the creation of the table only. After that, the natural sort depends on how mysql wants to sort it. But you can always use an ORDER BY clause in your queries.